# Linking LLVM getOrInsertFunction to a external c++ function in a LLVM pass

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, instrumentation

I have written a LLVM pass that inserts a call to a external function (`foo`) in a `C`(count.c) file. Later when I link `C` file's object that contains `foo` function with LLVM instrumented c++ file, it works fine. The C file which contains foo function, looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int count = 0;

void foo(int id) {
    count++;
    printf("id = $d,  count = %d\n", id, count);
}
```

I create a call from LLVM pass using this code snippet:

```
ArrayRef<Type *> paramTypes = {Type::getInt8Ty(Ctx)};
Type *retType = Type::getVoidTy(Ctx);
FunctionType *funcType = FunctionType::get(retType, paramTypes, false);

FunctionCallee callee = M.getOrInsertFunction("foo", funcType);
```

All this works fine as long as `foo` function is in a `C` file. But if foo is in a `C++` file, ld returns `undefined references to 'foo'`

Is there a way to link an external function in a C++ file to llvm `getOrInsertFunction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to make the C++ function as `extern`.

foo.cpp can look like:

```cpp
extern "C" {

void foo(int id) {
    count++;
    printf("id = $d,  count = %d\n", id, count);
}

}
```

`extern` C tells the compiler to not mangle the name of scoped functions. You can learn more about name mangling and extern C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c)